# What is the fastest way to find a file in a directory tree

Tags: c++, windows, search

I have a directory tree similar to the one below. It contains around 30,000 files in total.

```
rootDir
rootDir\subDir1
rootDir\subDir1\subSubDir1
rootDir\subDir1\subSubDir2
rootDir\subDir2
rootDir\subDir2\subSubDir1
rootDir\subDir3
...
rootDir\subDirN
```

What is the fastest way to find a file from a directory structure such as the one above based on it's name using C++ on Windows?

Comment: `system("dir /S <filename>");`. That's the fastest way to write code to do this. ;-)

Comment: I don't think the API has an inbuilt "fast search" of a directory structure, you have to roll it yourself: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do have [Windows Desktop Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965726.aspx) or [Windows Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362.aspx) operating (or the target computer *might* have it, anyway), you can use [ISearchFolderItemFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775176.aspx) (or [`ISearchDesktop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965714.aspx), for WDS) to have it do a search for you.

If there's no pre-existing index, nearly the only way to do this is with [`FirstFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx), [`FindnextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428.aspx) and [`FindClose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364413.aspx). I generally recommend *against* the obvious recursive method of doing the search though -- a breadth-first search is usually at least as fast, and depending on the situation, can easily be twice as fast.

To do a breadth-first search, you maintain a collection (I usually use a priority queue, but a normal queue, stack, etc., will also work) of sub-directories you haven't searched yet. You start a search by entering the starting directory into the collection, and then having your search function do it's thing. Your search runs in a loop, continuing searching until the collection is empty. When it encounters a directory, it adds it to the collection.

Comment: breadth-first is harder, takes more memory, and I can't think of a situation where it's twice as fast. (Other than the file not being nested deeply, which isn't a good assumption)  Also, for the data structure I'd recommend the deque, which was designed for those operations.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I've tested both for simply traversing an entire tree, and breadth-first is *usually* at least a little faster, and twice as fast isn't rare. I can only speculate about why, but better locality of reference improving cache utilization seems quite likely. If you have to roll your own collection code, BFS might be harder, but with existing collections, it's little (if any) more difficult at all. The majority of it comes down to replacing `changedir(subdir); search(name); changedir("..");` with `dirs.push_back(subdir_name)`, and adding a `while (!dirs.empty())` around the outside.

Comment: locality of reference makes sense, I simply didn't expect it to make that dramatic of a difference.  Since you've timed it, and it's not _that_ much harder, then I'll agree that breadth first is better.

Comment: GetFileInformationByHandleEx (with FileIdBothDirectoryInfo) is probably faster than using FindFirstFile and FileNextFile.  I haven't had a chance to try it yet so I'm not certain.  (In Windows 8 FileFullDirectoryInfo should be even faster!)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the answer you're looking for, but having an index of available files in the file system optimized for the search patterns you support would be fastest.

If you're using some API to do it, it simply depends on how well you write code, profile and improve it. :)